# How to dynamically build Calculated Properties with Select-Object?

Tags: powershell, select-object, calculated-property

I query a REST API which returns a JSON with many subproperties that I need to extract using a calculated property hashtable with `Select-Object`. The subproperty has always the same name (`result`), and I want to use a filter or a function to avoid rewriting the hashtable all along.

Example:

```
some json | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object @{ Name="name"; Expression={ $_."name".result}}, @{ Name="year"; Expression={ $_."year".result}}, etc.
```

I thought it will be more convenient (and easy) to build a filter that would return the hashtable:

```
filter Get-Result {
     param (
         [string]$field
     )
     @{N=$field; E={ $_."$field".result}}
}
```

But $field is not replaced in Expression block. I don't understand why

```
> Get-Result -field "year"

Name                           Value
----                           -----
N                              year
E                               $_."$field".result
```

How to make `$_."$field".result` be `$_."year".result` in Expression block?

Comment: It won't be "year" in the expression block but you can make it remember that value once invoked, just need to `@{N=$field; E={ $_."$field".result}.GetNewClosure()}`

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know about `GetNewClosure`. A big step for my PowerShell knowledge for sure!  Unfortunately, `filter Get-Result { param ( [string]$field )  @{  N=$field; E={ $_."$field".result}.GetNewClosure()   } }`  yields the same result as above  `E =  $_."$field".result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options: closure or source code generation

### 1. Create a closure

You can call `GetNewClosure()` on the scriptblock passed to the `Expression` entry - this will cause PowerShell's internal compiler to create a dynamic module that "remembers" the value bound to `$fieldName` (or any other variable references to the scope where `GetNewClosure()` is called):

```
# create some dummy objects for testing
$objects = 1..10|%{
  [pscustomobject]@{
    name = @{ result = "Name_${_}" }
    year = @{ result = Get-Random -Minimum 1900 -Maximum 2025 }
  }
}

# define filter to generate property expression tables
filter Get-Result {
   # to take advantage of pipeline input, use `$_`
   $fieldName = "$_"
   # return property table with closure attached
   @{N=$fieldName; E={ $_."$fieldName".result}.GetNewClosure()}
}

# this now works as expected
$objects |Select-Object -Property ('name','year' |Get-Result)
```

### 2. Construct scriptblock from source code

The alternative is to construct the expression block by generating its source code and then passing that off to `[scriptblock]::Create()`:

```
filter Get-Result {
   # to take advantage of pipeline input, use `$_`
   $fieldName = "$_"

   # escape any literal `'`s
   $escapedName = [System.Management.Automation.Language.CodeGeneration]::EscapeSingleQuotedStringContent($fieldName)
   $expressionText = '$_.''{0}''.result' -f $escapedName
   $expression = [scriptblock]::Create($expressionText)

   # return property table with closure attached
   @{N=$fieldName; E=$expression}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I should have thought about `[scriptblock]::Create($expressionText)` indeed.
I see that $expressionText = `$_.'{0}'.result" -f $fieldName` also works, although `$_` is replaced. Why is that?

Comment: @jgran because you use `"` instead of `'` - don't do that!

Comment: What is very cool with your solution, is that I can group the fields which have the subproperty `result` : `("name" | Get-Result), ("year" | Get-Result)` is equivalent to `( "name", "year" | Get-Result)`. Logic, buI I haven't though of this consequence.

Comment: @jgran it does, but you should be a little careful mixing and matching like that, otherwise you might end up passing a nested array to `Select-Object`. Instead, do `Select-Object -Property @('name','year'|Get-Result; 'otherprop'|Get-Result)` - `@(...)` will produce a flat array instead (which is what you want here)